# ESP8266 Core 1.3.0 and Lwip sources

Tags: esp8266, lwip

i am trying to modify the lwip to get additional functionality.
However i am unable to pair my ESP8266 core version with lwip sources.

Here is what ESP returns by calling:

```
Serial.printf( "SDK: %s\n", ESP.getSdkVersion() );
```

Output:

> SDK: 1.3.0

In this version, the lwip is stored in libraries/ESP8266WIFI - but there are no sources to compile, only headers and already built library:

[image]

[image]

How do i get the lwip sources for this ESP8266 Core version please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it,
recompiled it,
tested it,
works.

https://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=951